Como compartir correctamente mi proyecto en XAMPP a otros equipos de mi red local?
Tengo un proyecto en PHP 8 y JavaScript en un pc donde está instalado XAMPP en su última versión a septiembre del 2024. y necesito que otros equipos dentro de la misma red, puedan acceder a este proyecto. Es algo "Sencillo", lo he hecho en varias ocasiones pero en esta oportunidad no he logrado que los equipos visualicen correctamente mi proyecto y no entiendo la razón.
Agradezco si alguien me puedo ayudar.

Los equipos tienen acceso a la ip del pc que funge el rol de servidor
Los equipos tienen acceso correctamente a PhpMyAdmin
Los equipos tienen acceso a otros directorios de mi htdocs y los visualiza correctamente

Al ingresar desde otro pc al directorio que contiene la aplicación que necesito, el navegador en la consola del inspector muestra el siguiente error:

net::ERR_CONECTION_REFUSED
En todos los archivos que requiere la aplicación para funcionar (css, js, etc)

Access has been blocked by CORS policy
En los controles de JavaScript


Cabe aclarar que la aplicación funciona perfectamente en el "Servidor" y no tiene ni un solo error en consola ni nada parecido a lo que muestra el navegador de los otros equipos.
Es primera vez que me ocurre esto, por favor ayuda!
Muchas gracias.

Y buscaste en google qué significa ese errro CORS que dices?? Porque sin más información y viendo que te da error de CORS... La respuesta lógica es pensar que ese es tu problema. No podemos ayudarte sin más información... y si es problema de CORS, necesitas cambiar la configuración de CORS en tu proyecto, no puedo decirte cómo tampoco porque decir "es php" no es mucha información sinceramente

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Debes arreglar CORS en tu back

¿Usas la misma url tanto desde el servidor como desde los otros equipos?

Abrir puertos en el Firewall?? Aunque tengas error de CORS, tu app debería cargar. Yo creo que lo que no tienes es comunicación entre server y clientes. Pon una captura del error que se ve en el navegador de un cliente...

Busca el archivo xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf y cambia Listen 80 por Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Revisa que el archivo de hosts no esté redirigiendo el trafico. si usas windows este archivo esta en C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
Desactiva el firewall o agrega una regla para abrir el puerto 80.
Para resolver CORS:
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
</IfModule>

Revisa estar utilizando la dirección IP del servidor en tu red local. Por ejemplo, si la IP del PC es 192.168.1.10, para acceder desde el navegador de otro equipo tenes que usar:
http://192.168.1.10/NOMBRETUPROYECTO

No te olvides de reiniciar XAMMP al terminar estos cambios.
Saludos.
